rust [mockall return_once] borrowed value does not live long enough
I am learning Rust and I am writing a unit test using mockall library.
I have some String in my test and I want to pass it to multiple mock closures.
If I pass it directly, then I understand that I would move the ownership to the closure.
So instead I am converting it to &str, but then I get "borrowed value does not live long enough" and "argument requires that  is borrowed for `'static".
I can't uderstand why the compiler can't figure out that the String lives long enough as &str in this case. I can make it work using Rc, but I would like to know if there is easier way to fix this.
Here is the mockall return_once signature
use mockall::mock;

pub struct Setting {
    pub key: String,
}

impl Clone for Setting {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Setting {
            key: self.key.clone(),
        }
    }
}

pub trait TSettingRepository {
    fn get(&self, id: &str) -> Setting;
}

mock! {
    pub SettingRepository{}

    impl TSettingRepository for SettingRepository {
        fn get(&self, id: &str) -> Setting {
            todo!()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let key_str: String = "some String from external function".to_string();
    let key: &str = &key_str; //<- borrowed value does not live long enough

    let mut setting_repository = MockSettingRepository::new();

    setting_repository.expect_get().return_once(|_| Setting {
        key: key.to_string(),
    });

    setting_repository.expect_get().return_once(|_| Setting {
        key: key.to_string(),
    });
}


Because return_once takes a 'static closure, which means that the closure is not allowed to capture non-'static references. That's what MockallF: … + 'static means in the docs you linked

I see. Now the question is how to make the &'static str from String.
I managed to do it using let key: &str = key_str.leak() which works, but seems like a hacky way. I guess for the unit test it's fine, but in a long production program it's not. Is there a better way?

You can just clone String.

Or convert it to Rc<str> and clone that if you don't want to clone the string data.

Cloning doesn't work here because of the 'static lifetime. It's the same error. Apparently the scope of main is not the same as 'static, so the String or the clone are dropped after main. All of this is a bit strange at first sight, but kind of makes sense.
And using Rc works like I mentioned in the question.
Anyway, thanks @Jmb for pointing me to the 'static reference. I am satisified this to be the answer if you will.

Cloning works, but you need to clone outside the closure: playground.

Oh, you mean cloning for each closure. And I meant cloning the original string. Yes, this will work as well. However, in my unit test I will stick with the leak approach, as this doesn't require cloning for each closure. I am using this String in many places. But on production definitely clone or Rc. Thanks again.

As suggested by @Jmb, the mockall methods require 'static and dynamic String argument cannot be converted to 'static in obvious way. One hacky way is to call leak() on the String. Alternatively we can clone() the String to each closure to pass ownership.
